# Grouping Pandas Dataframe by multiple columns in order to get specific values

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, plot, grouping

lets describe my Problem.

I get a lot of data out of the database. For example it loos like:

```
d = [
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 15, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 14, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 16, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2021 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 30, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 32, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 31, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2021 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 120, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 140, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Weight', 'Value': 130, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2021 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.23, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.23, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.24, 'Product': 'Apple', 'Year': 2021 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.81, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.83, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 0.9, 'Product': 'Banana', 'Year': 2021 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 2.31, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2019 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 2.29, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2020 },
{'Tag': 'Price', 'Value': 2.41, 'Product': 'Papaya', 'Year': 2021 }
]
```

I create a dataframe with this command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Then the data looks like:

```
     Tag    Value   Product Year
0   Weight  15.00   Apple   2019
1   Weight  14.00   Apple   2020
2   Weight  16.00   Apple   2021
3   Weight  30.00   Banana  2019
4   Weight  32.00   Banana  2020
5   Weight  31.00   Banana  2021
6   Weight  120.00  Papaya  2019
...
```

So far so fine. Now I want to sort and filter this dataframe to make nice plots. For example, I want to show the price (Tag == 'Price') of the last years. That means on my X Axis I want to have all of the products and on the y axis I have the corresponsing prices. I want to have for example for each year an individual dataset, labeled with that year. In this example in a bar chart I get 3 bars for each product, each representing the price of a year.

What is the best way of doing it with pandas?

At the moment I am iterating through all of the data, finding the correct ones and filling up new arrays, just to put the newly created arrays into my plots. But that seems not the ideal way.

So question is, how to get my axes for the plots? How yould you solve this problem in a most elegant way? Just with pandas? Possible?

I am excited, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subset your data to the `'Price'` rows, and then reshape with a `pivot` so the organization is appropriate for the plotting a bar plot -- a row for each product and a column for each year.

```
dfp = (df[df['Tag'].eq('Price')]
          .pivot(index='Product', columns='Year', values='Value'))
#Year     2019  2020  2021
#Product                  
#Apple    0.23  0.23  0.24
#Banana   0.81  0.83  0.90
#Papaya   2.31  2.29  2.41

dfp.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ec='k')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# set width of bar
barWidth = 0.25
fig = plt.subplots(figsize =(12, 8))
 
# set height of bar
Apple = list(df[(df.Product=='Apple')&(df.Tag=='Price')].Value)
Banana = list(df[(df.Product=='Banana')&(df.Tag=='Price')].Value)
Papaya = list(df[(df.Product=='Papaya')&(df.Tag=='Price')].Value)
 
# Set position of bar on X axis
br1 = np.arange(len(Apple))
br2 = [x + barWidth for x in br1]
br3 = [x + barWidth for x in br2]
 
# Make the plot
plt.bar(br1, Apple, color ='r', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='Apple')
plt.bar(br2, Banana, color ='g', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='Banana')
plt.bar(br3, Papaya, color ='b', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='Papaya')
 
# Adding Xticks
plt.xlabel('Year', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 25)
plt.ylabel('Price', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 25)
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(Apple))],['2019','2020','2021'])
 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

---

[image: Bar Chart]